# Quartz Scheduler not return values method executing in every 3 minutes

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We are running one schedule using Quartz and getting the updated data from table in the executeinternal method, but how to access that java object from main method.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("SlaTime", "SlaTimeGroup",
                    SlaUptimeImpl.class);
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("SlaTrigger", "SlaGroup",
                    "0/10 * 0-23 ? * *");
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
            scheduler.start();



        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Here we are executing the query in this `SlaUptimeImpl` class but not able to get the return data here because am executing the query in `ExecuteInternal` Method which have return type as `void`.

anyone help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a data map to your job, thanks to [JobBuilder#usingDataMap()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html#usingJobData%28org.quartz.JobDataMap%29). I think you could put an "observer" into this map, retrieve the observer at job execution, and notify it about the result.

While scheduling your job:

```
JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
map.put("myObserver", new MyObserver());

JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(SlaUptimeImpl.class).withIdentity("SlaTime", "SlaTimeGroup").usingJobData(map).build();
```

And in your job:

```
public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    ...

    ((MyObserver) context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("myObserver")).notify(result);
}
```

Comment: given error try {
   Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
   JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
   map.put("slaUptimeImpl", new SlaUptimeImpl());
   //JobDetail job = newJob(SlaUptimeImpl.class).withIdentity("myJob").build();
 <- Error giving here---> JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob().withIdentity("SlaTime", "SlaGroup").usingJobData(map).build();       
CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("SlaTrigger", "SlaGroup","0/10 * 0-23 ? * *");
 scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
   System.out.println("map="+map);
      scheduler.start();
   
   
  }

Comment: If you get an `IllegalArgumentException` ("Job class cannot be null."), then the edit I've just made should be fine. If you get another exception, please give me more detail about the error.